# Python Code That Creates Username Using OOP Methods.

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am trying to create a code using two different classes one called User that stores information about a user. The user class has Attributes of _username, _wins, _ties, and _losses. With methods of **int**, get_username, get_user_wins, set_user_wins, get_user_losses, set_user_losses, get_user_ties, set_user_ties,and display_user. The other class is called Users that stores and displays a user_object. Then another program that uses both classes and a menu of; [1] Create User, [2] Display Users, and [3] Exit

I am confused on how to get this to work, the code that I have tried to write, can anyone please help me figure out how to write a code like this.

```
import Users
import random
#User Class
class User:
    def __init__(self, username, wins, ties, losses):
        self._username = username
        self._wins = wins
        self._ties = random.randint(0,10)
        self._losses = random.randint(0,10)
    #Returns value of username field 
    def get_username(self):
        return self._username
    #Returns value of wins field
    def get_user_wins(self):
        return self._wins
    #Returns vaule of ties fied
    def get_user_ties(self):
        return self._ties
    #Returns the value of losses field
    def get_user_losses(self):
        return self._losses
    #Displays the username and stats
    def display_users(self):
        print("User List")
        print("---------")
        for user in (users.create_user()):
            print("Username: ", get_username())
            print("Wins\tTies\tLosses")   
            print(str(get_user_wins())+"\t"+str(get_user_ties())+"\t"+str(get_user_losses( )))



#usersclasscode
import User
class Users:
    def __init__(self, user_list):
        self._user_list = []
    def create_user(self):
        username = input("Please enter the user name: ")
        wins = int(input("How many wins does "+username+" have? "))
        ties = 0
        losses = 0
        self._created_user = User.User(username, wins, ties, losses)
        self._user_list.append(self._created_user) 
        return self._user_list

#usermanagercode
import User
import Users

print("User Menu")
print("---------")
print("[1] Create User")
print("[2] Display Users")
print("[3] Exit")

calc = True
while(calc):
    a = int(input("Enter the number in bracket for what you would like to do: "))
    if a==1:
        users.create_user())        
    elif a==2:
        user.display_users(self)
    elif a==3:
        calc = False
```